# exception type in Observable.retrywhen

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

i am new to rxJava, this is probably very stupid question but i am not able to figure out how to find the type of exception in retry when.
i want to retry on a particular exception (eg Io Exception), but on others
i want to pass the exception down the chain.

```
public Observable<List<String>> getData()
{
    return apiConsumer.getData()
            .retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>()
            {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable)
                {
                    // if(exception type == io exception)
                    return observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    //else
                    //  dont retry, pass the exception to onError
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
return apiConsumer.getData().retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
        return observable.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                if(throwable instanceof IOException) {
                   // Retry code
                   // For example: retry after 5seconds
                   return Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                // Pass the throwable
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exception type as seen in the code below.  The lambda inside `flatMap` will be called for each error, where you can check the type via `instanceof`.  I haven't worked with RXJava in a while and didn't test if your `return observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` will still work fyi :)

```
public Observable<List<String>> getData() {
    return apiConsumer.getData().retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {  
        // This lambda will be called for each error. Check the type:
        if (error instanceof IOException) {
            return observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        //Dont retry, pass the exception to onError
      })
    )
}
```

My answer is based on [this tutorial](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/), which provides more information about the topic.